# Getting NoClassDefFoundError while trying to get Firestore Database instance

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-cloud-firestore, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to get reference of the Cloud Firestore database but I'm getting the following error

> Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/Preconditions;

I have gone through all the documentation and checked whatever I could.

- I have added Xamarin.Google.Guava package in my project
- Enabled Multidex, cleaned and rebuild the solution
- I am not using Proguard
- FirebaseApp is not null
- I have changed the build action of GoogleServicesJson to None and  manually build the FirebaseApp options but got the same result

Following is package list

> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design      {28.0.0.1}
>   Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore          {71.1705.0}
>   Xamarin.Google.Guava                {27.1.0.2}

Here is my GetDatabase method

```
public FirebaseFirestore GetDatabase()
        {
            FirebaseFirestore data_base;
            var app = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context);
            if (app == null)
            {
                var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .SetProjectId("deliveryapp-254615")
                .SetApplicationId("deliveryapp-254615")
                .SetApiKey("AIzaSyD9HOqiYHFLsT4RspeZyElbhhqq5tNBXPs")
                .SetDatabaseUrl("https://deliveryapp-254615.firebaseio.com")
                .SetStorageBucket("deliveryapp-254615.appspot.com")
                .Build();

                app = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context, options);
            }

            data_base = FirebaseFirestore.GetInstance(app);

            return data_base
        }
```

Following is the debug log

```
10-03 19:08:39.154 D/FirebaseApp(28559): com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId is not linked. Skipping initialization.
10-03 19:08:39.155 D/FirebaseApp(28559): com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
10-03 19:08:39.156 D/FirebaseApp(28559): com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement is not linked. Skipping initialization.
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/Function;
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at void mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(android.view.View) (View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:-2)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at void mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(android.view.View) (View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at boolean android.view.View.performClick() (View.java:6297)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at void android.view.View$PerformClick.run() (View.java:24797)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:790)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:99)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6626)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:438)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:811)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.base.Function" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Voidron.Delivery_DemoApp-d9Ckk53XN-uid0HuJbaR0A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Voidron.Delivery_DemoApp-d9Ckk53XN-uid0HuJbaR0A==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.Voidron.Delivery_DemoApp-d9Ckk53XN-uid0HuJbaR0A==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
10-03 19:08:39.180 I/zygote  (28559):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using input from https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/258

All I did was downgrade the package of Guava to 27.1.0.0 which seemed to resolve the issue